# Logs websphere 8.5.5.12 and elasticsearch 5.4 error on start

Tags: java, elasticsearch, log4j, websphere-8

I'm trying to use elasticsearch with websphere 8.5 I added some dependencies of logs like

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.24</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.28</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.28</version>
        </dependency>
```

and when I start my server I get this error

```
   [05/01/18 16:38:41:894 WET] 0000005c ecs           W com.ibm.ws.ecs.internal.scan.context.impl.ScannerContextImpl scanJAR unable to open input stream for resource META-INF/versions/9/org/apache/logging/log4j/util/StackLocator.class in archive WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.9.1.jar
                                     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to exclude the log4 jars from WebSphere annotation processing using the instructions at this [IBM KnowledgeCenter topic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQTP_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/trun_app_reduce_annot.html).

Answer (score 0):

Modify the server property **Ignore-Scanning-Archives** in order to ignore the scanJar for this library.

There are 2 different ways for do that:

1. Modify the server directly: 
   Add the jar in the file **{WAS}/properties/amm.filter.properties**

> Ignore-Scanning-Archives = log4j-api-2.9.1.jar

2. Using Manifest file: 
   Is practically the same, add the property **Ignore-Scanning-Archives** inside your Manifest in the EAR file. 
   If the project is a Maven project add new xml tag in the **maven-ear-plugin**

> ```
> <plugin>
>  <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
>  ...
>  <manifestEntries>
>   <Ignore-Scanning-Archives>log4j-api-2.9.1.jar</Ignore-Scanning-Archives>
> ```